# Are PROLOG facts bilateral?

Tags: prolog

So I have just started programming in PROLOG (SWI distribution). I have good logic bases and I am familiar with facts, rules, quantification and all that vocabulary.

As far as I know, you can define a fact such as:

```
married(a,b).
```

And I know that if you make a query like:

```
?: married(X,b).
```

The answer will be "a". My question is, if I wanted to make a rule that used the fact previously declared, it will consider that "a is married to b", but will it consider that "b is married to a" or do I have to declare another fact like:

```
married(b,a).
```

for it to work? Same for any kind of bilateral relationship that can be represented as a fact.

Comment: What is cuantificators?

Comment: Maybe I wrote it wrong (sorry for my english!). I mean predicate logic "cuantificators?" such as Exists(X) or ForAll(X).

Comment: No need to apologize for your English. I am sure I don't know your language. Is [quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification)  the correct word?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean if the relation is automatically symmetric? Then no - suppose you have a directed graph with `edge(a,b)`, then you would not want the other direction `edge(b,a)` to be inferred. Also, what about relations of arity greater than 2?

You can always create the symmetric closure of a predicate as:

```
r_sym(X,Y) :-
  r(X,Y).
r_sym(X,Y) :-
  r(Y,X).
```

Using a new predicate name prevents infinite derivation chains `r(X,Y) -> r(Y,X) -> r(X,Y) -> ....`.

Comment: Didn't consider the graph situation, and that makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much for your answer!